# How to fill a field in a table using ModelBuilder ToolBox

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arctoolbox

How to fill a field (set a value) in a table using ModelBuilder ToolBox.

Answer (score 3):

Go to "Arctoolbox-> data management tool-> Field ", find the "Calculate Field" tool and drag into ModelBuilder, double click the calculate field, input a value which you want to set or use expression to set the value.
Hope it works, good luck!

Comment: Thank you for toy appreciated reply, but I would like to fill it in parameter no need to calculate no values. It's just an ID code that I must add in a table after an operation. 
Best regards

Comment: Well, go to "Arctoolbox-> data management tool-> Field ", find the "Add Field" tool and drag into ModelBuilder. I am not sure this is what you want. or please write the details or give a image of you want.